# Java: Callback to main Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, callback

How can I make the callback execute in the "main thread"?

```
@Test
void threadTest() throws InterruptedException {

    System.out.println("main thread:" + Thread.currentThread());

    new Thread(new AsyncTask(this::callback)).start();

    Thread.sleep(1100);
}

private void callback() {
    System.out.println("callback executed in: " + Thread.currentThread());
}

static class AsyncTask implements Runnable{
  private final  Runnable runnable;

    public AsyncTask(Runnable runnable) {
        this.runnable = runnable;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("other thread: " + Thread.currentThread());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        this.runnable.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: SImple: just don't execute it from the spawned thread but from the main thread. To be more precise: you can't _tell_ the main thread to "now do this" but you could write your code so that it waits for some flag/status and run the "callback" then. This could be done via joining the spawned thread, blocking on futures that might be returned (not from Runnable though) or actively waiting for some variable to be set. But as Mark stated this seems to be a XY problem and thus we need to know what you're really after in order to provide specific help.

Comment: The actual case is a library that provides reactive pipelines, reading form a broker. It wraps messages into a class that has an acknowledgement method. The pipeline allows the user to register asynchronous handlers that are executed in an arbitrary thread and call the acknowledgment where they want to. The Message wrappers acknowledge method is a callback that must be executed on that same thread that subscribes to the broker, since the underlying client is not thread safe.

Comment: Re, "...a callback that must be executed on that same thread..." Like @Thomas said, you can't _make_ the main thread change what it's doing and execute some arbitrary function. The only way your code can do anything "on" a client thread is if the client thread _calls_ your code. The best you can do is provide a method that your client periodically calls _from_ their "main" thread, and have that method execute any callbacks that are due.

Comment: When using reactive processing you also need to think "non-blocking". This means you shouldn't "call" any thread but basically just provide tasks for threads which they can execute when they have capacity. That way the user provided handler might just be a task that puts the acknowledgement task to the main thread's pool and which can carry another task to be put into another pool to be executed after acknowledgement - if this is required.

Comment: @Thomas Yeah, that's what I usually do. The problem is that the acknowledgment method of the client is not thread safe.

Comment: As I said, just use separate pools and put the acknowledgement task into the task pool for the right thread (the one that is associated with the client) so it can be picked up when that thread is looking for work.

Comment: Yes, that probably is that way to go. I just wrote a proxy class around the message interface, that keeps a reference to the subscribing `ExecutorService`. That's bypassing the threading behaviour of the reactive pipeline, but should work. 
Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to force execution of `callback()` in particular `ExecutorService`:

```java
class ConcTest {
    ExecutorService mainExecutor  = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    @Test
    void threadTest() throws Exception {
        mainExecutor.submit(() -> {
            System.out.println("main thread:" + Thread.currentThread());
            new Thread(new AsyncTask(mainExecutor, this::callback)).start();
            sleep(1100);
        }).get();
    }

    private void callback() {
        System.out.println("callback executed in: " + Thread.currentThread());
    }

    private static void sleep(int millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    static class AsyncTask implements Runnable{
        private final ExecutorService mainExecutor;
        private final Runnable runnable;

        public AsyncTask(ExecutorService mainExecutor, Runnable runnable) {
            this.mainExecutor = mainExecutor;
            this.runnable = runnable;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("other thread: " + Thread.currentThread());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                mainExecutor.submit(runnable).get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This prints

```
main thread:Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main]
other thread: Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
callback executed in: Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually this could be simplified by submitting `() -> mainExecutor.execute(this::callback)`. Unfortunately I don't have access to the executor at that point. However, I like the approach with `submit(...).get()`.